# How do you combine 3 existing band pass filters to make a triplexer with 50 Ohm ports?

Tags: rf, filter, impedance-matching, band-pass, microstrip

I have designed 3 microstrip band pass filters that each have a good 50 ohm match at the target frequencies (2 m, 70cm and 13cm bands) and I want to combine them into a triplexer to split one signal into three different frequencies.

Of course if I just connect them together on one side, then the behavior changes because of impedance differences.

What is a good way to connect filters to maintain 50 Ohms on all 4 ports of the triplexer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *What is a good way to connect filters to maintain 50 Ohms on all 4
> ports of the triplexer?*

The output ports will likely maintain their 50 Ω characteristics if each sees a 50 Ω source impedance at their input. So, each filter needs to be fed separately from a 50 Ω source. This then boils down to making a matching network for each filter's input port that looks like 150 Ω at the network's input (so three in parallel make 50 Ω) and looks like 50 Ω on the matching network's output: -

[image]

[Inter-active resistive matching calculator](http://www.stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Zmatch%20basic.html).

The above is bidirectional and therefore you connect the "RL" side (150 Ω) to your 50 Ω source (with the other two matching networks) and the "RIN" side to your filter input.

Of course you can use less "lossy" matching networks as in [this calculator](http://www.stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Zmatch%20Lpad%20LP.html) but, you need to check bandwidth requirements are sufficient to meet your needs.

Maybe a pi-matching-network could help because you can adjust the bandwidth to suit your needs: -

[image]

[Inter-active pi-matching-network calculator](http://www.stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Zmatch%20PI%20LP.html).

Comment: Thank you for the hint about needing 150 Ohm inputs! Maybe I can re-optimize my filters with 150 Ohms on the input side before combining them

Comment: Sounds like a shrewd idea.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a couple 3 dB splitters or redesign the filter to crossover the 2m signal such it is high impedance out of band and 1 splitter for the 2 higher frequencies that are closer together.